# New File Action in Finder

Tags: finder, uti, folders

[image]

Why finder doesn't have 'New File', but 'New Folder'?
Is there any way/tool for having 'New File' in Finder?

### ADDED

Pathfinder provides the feature of making 'New File'. I need this function in Finder.

[image]

Comment: What type of file? You would need a large sub-menu like in Windows letting you select the file type.

Comment: Well, just letting me give the full file name would work to get any type of file.

Answer (score 2):

The idea in OS X is, that you open an Application and create the file while you are working. This simply because creating the file beforehand is kind of awkward:

> Create file > open file > edit

Of course if you just need dummy files, then you can make those from Terminal.app, but I'd be careful with that if you are not used to it already.

The command is: `touch filename`

Comment: Actually 'touch something' is the method that I'm using. However, I need to open Terminal.app, cd to the directory, and run the command to get it done. Just write clicking would be better if possible.

Comment: Sometimes its much better to be on the relevant folder and create file from there rather than doing the otherway around.

Comment: "The idea in OS X is, that you open an Application and create the file while you are working." I know, and it drives me crazy. I hate the Application-centric model, where files belong to Apps in a sense. I prefer the file-centric model of HCI, it's the files (and the data they hold) that we really care about in the end.

Answer (score -1):

proseek you can add to finder the extension "shellhere", that's great!